# JSON _POST empty from android HttpPost

Tags: php, android, json, http-post

I Dont get it my _POST is empty

I create a JSONOBJECT I pass it to the HTTPPost
Like this:

```
   HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL);

                StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
                se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
                        "application/json"));
                post.setEntity(se);
                response = client.execute(post);
```

Yet it shows up as an empty array

Here is the FULL code

Create me JSON Object (can debug this and wactch it fill

```
public static final JSONObject GetJSONObject(Customer customer) {

        try {
            JSONObject values = new JSONObject();
            values.put(Customer.KEY_NAME, customer._name); // Contact Name
            values.put(Customer.KEY_PH_NO, customer._phone); // Contact Phone
            values.put(Customer.KEY_EMAIL, customer._email);
            values.put(Customer.KEY_UUID, customer._UUID);
            values.put(Customer.KEY_GEOUUID, customer._geoUUID);
            values.put(Customer.KEY_SALESREPUUID, customer._salesRepUUID);
            values.put(Customer.KEY_CUST_LAST_UPDATE, customer.last_update);
            values.put(Customer.KEY_CUST_NOTES, customer._notes);
            return values;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d("ERROR", e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Start Send Thread

```
        ma.ShowToastMsg("Updating Contract To mySQL" + customer._name);
    mh.sendJSONTHREAD("http://.php",
            GetJSONObject(customer));
public void sendJSONTHREAD(final String URL, final JSONObject json) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            sendJson(URL, json);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Send it

```
public void sendJson(final String URL, final JSONObject json) {
    Looper.prepare(); // For Preparing Message Pool for the child Thread
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000); // Timeout
                                                                            // Limit
    HttpResponse response;

    try {
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL);

        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
        se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
                "application/json"));
        post.setEntity(se);
        response = client.execute(post);


        /* Checking response */
        if (response != null) {
            Log.d("RESPONSE", EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));

            //InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent(); // Get the
                                                                // data in
                                                                // the
                                                                // entity
            //Log.d("HTTPPOST", in.toString());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // createDialog("Error", "Cannot Estabilish Connection");
    }

    Looper.loop(); // Loop in the message queue

}
```

AND the PHP side of things

```
include("settings.php");

mysql_connect($loginURL,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die("-9");

echo var_dump($_POST);

$varname = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['name']));
$varemail = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
$varphone = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['phone']));
$varUUID = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['UUID']));
$vargeopointUUID = $_POST['geopointUUID'];

echo var_dump($_POST);
```

---

the echo var_dump($_POST) - returns me array(0){}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A POST doesn't expect JSON to be passed, but rather name/value pairs as the following:

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key1", "value1"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key2", "value2"));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

If you wanted to pass JSON to php, you would need to inspect and parse `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`.

One approach (cited out by the OP) to parse raw past data is as follows (php):

```
$obj = json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA); $varname =$obj->{'name'};
```

Comment: Don't get it - there are plenty of tutorials and questions on here with people successfully using _POST

Comment: I checked HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA and all of my data is inside of it - however i cant get variables filled out - if I do json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA['name']); they return back as '{'

Comment: Try `print_r( json_decode( $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA ) )` to see if it parses correctly -- or avoid the whole mess by sending a URLEncodedFormEntity as explained above. If you're just sending key/value pairs and nothing nested, there's really no reason to post the data in json.

Comment: - that seems to print properly... each item prints to screen like this - [UUID] => d3a15359-bc45-417d-b228-28dc561df773
so can't I just assign that to a variable like this then??
$varemail = json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA['email']);

Comment: You'd want to decode FIRST, then access -- `json_decode( $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA )[ 'email' ]`

Comment: $varname = json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)['name'];

02-11 22:57:15.699: D/RESPONSE(18214): <b>Parse error</b>: syntax error, unexpected '[' in <b>/home/.php</b> on line <b>27</b><br/>

Comment: This does appear to work: $obj = json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
$varname =$obj->{'name'};

Comment: placed this as answer; however, would recommend putting that last line I wrote as part of your original post for easy translation for stumbles later (thanks for help)

Comment: Sure it wouldn't just be -- `$obj->name`? My php is a bit rusty. (and yes, amended answer for future readers)